# given array with n numbers such that arr[0] is even and arr[n-1] is odd, find index i such that a[i] is even and a[i+1] is odd

Tags: arrays, binary-search

Suppose I have an array A with n numbers, so that the first element of this array is even,  and last one is odd- I would like to write an function which  find index i , such that A[i] is even and A[i+1] is odd. 
The function is to return the found index; if there is not any such index, return -1.

**The time complexity of that solution must be log(n)**.

I have been thinking of using binary search in that case.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
int findIndex(int A[], int n)
{
   int left=0,right=n-1,mid,i;

   while(left<=right)
    {
      mid=(left+right)\2;
      if (A[mid]%2==0 && A[mid+1]%2!=0)
        return mid;
      else if (A[mid]%2!=0)
        right=mid-1;
      else 
       left=mid+1;
    }
   return -1;
}
```

I am  not sure...

What do you think about it?
Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Why start in the middle? The first value is even, so that would be a more sensible place to start IMO.

Comment: By "a[1+1]", do you mean "a[_i_ +1]"?

Answer (score -1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < A.size()-1; i++){
    if((A[i]+A[i+1])%2 == 1){
        return i;
    }
}
```